# Method to calculate the distance between points and return point's distance to the origin in a 3D array (java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the distance between one point to another in a 3D array, and then returns the point's distance to the origin. What kind of method(s) could I use for this? How should I think? Are there any good tutorials about this (that aren't too basic)?  I'm a beginner and very new to methods and would really appreciate some help. :)

Comment: Do you know this big search engine called google? Start researching there first.

Comment: I've been searching for relevant information for hours, and couldn't find anything that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the math basics about calculating distance between two points in 3D: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/calculate-distance-in-3d-space

The relevant Java functions that will help you are:

- [`Math.sqrt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt-double-): square root (e.g. `Math.sqrt(6) => 2.44948974278`)
- [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-): raise first argument to the power of the second (e.g. `Math.pow(2,4) => 16`)

Give it a try and post your code if you want more specific help.